# Wordpress Menu Hover Effect - Remove blob_over

Tags: css

I have setup a custom class using the below CSS for the Donate button on this website but I cannot figure out how to remove this hover effect. Any ideas where I can start here?

URL:http://bantingresearchfoundation.ca/

My Custom Class CSS

```
.donate {
background:#4A1383;
padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
color: blue !important;
}

.donate a{
color: white !important;
}

.donate:hover{
background:#4A1383;
}
```

Comment: try .donate { pointer-events:none; } to disable hover effect

Comment: This disabled the button entirely, is there a way to use this to remove the effect but maintain the hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just remove the class from the html. (menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2898) That will save you a lot of time and lot of trouble

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain this a little more? Where would I remove the class from the HTML?